# Separate meta analyses by a variable

Tags: r, tapply

I am meta analyzing everything related to listening (e.g., listening and leadership, listening and job satisfaction, etc.).  I would like to have all the effects in a single file and run separate meta analyses based on topic. [I have some 70 topics].

I am a newcomer to R, and thought that the tapply function could work, but could not figure out how to use it.

To test the idea I tried to create a command that will run a separate meta-analysis for the variable r"moderator".  First, I successfully ran metacor with the variable as a moderator:

```
metacor(rho,N,Study,data=Leadership,comb.fixed=F,prediction=T,byvar=Leadership$Moderator)
```

Then, I tested successfully the logic of tapply:

```
tapply(Leadership$rho,Leadership$Moderator,mean)
```

Now, I wanted to replace the mean function with metacor and tried unsuccessfully to write

```
tapply(,Leadership$Moderator,metacor(rho,N,Study,data=Leadership,comb.fixed=F,prediction=T))
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Avi

Comment: You left the first argument to `tapply` blank by starting with a comma. The code should look like `tapply(Leadership$Moderator, function(args) ... do stuff ... )`

Comment: Removing the blank created

Comment: tapply(Leadership$Moderator,metacor(rho,N,Study,data=Leadership,comb.fixed=F,prediction=T))     
Error in tapply(Leadership$Moderator, metacor(rho, N, Study, data = Leadership,  : 
  arguments must have same length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In ngroup * (as.integer(index) - one) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In ngroup * nlevels(index) : NAs produced by integer overflow

Answer (score 0):

In

```
tapply(X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., simplify = TRUE)
```

replace `...` with optional arguments to FUN

```
tapply(Leadership$rho,Leadership$Moderator,metacor,n=N,studlab=Study,data=Leadership,comb.fixed=F,prediction=T)
```

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'N' not found

Answer (score 0):

The following code solve the problem -- I thank both commentators

```
    dlply(Leadership, .(Moderator), function(Leadership) metacor(rho,N,Study,data=Leadership,comb.fixed=F,prediction=T))
```